# Passport Error "Unauthenticated"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I´m using Laravel 5.5 & newest passport.

I try to secure my api via passport and implemented it with the offical laravel docu.

First I receive a Bearer-Token with an api-call to .../auth/token.
Then I try to make this get-request via postman:
HEAD:

```
X-CSRF-TOKEN: zkmOKxFxGSG75QdZjuhHJkwUJ18FkHWm3OUxzZ8j
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer bearer-token
```

And I always get the following answer: 
Status: 401: Unauthorized

```
{
    "error": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

I don´t know how to handle this. 
In my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Edit: 
I upgraded Laravel to v. 5.5

Comment: where did get `zkmOKxFxGSG75QdZjuhHJkwUJ18FkHWm3OUxzZ8j` ? is this the Bearer-Token you got from calling `/auth/token` ?

Comment: I added "<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">" to my website and copied it.

Comment: If you're defining your route in the `api.php` file, then you don't need `csrf-token` at all. You just need to send the token in the `Authorization` header. Are replacing `bearer-token` with the actual token?

Comment: okay. It was a try, I found in some answers here. 
The Authorization-Header with Bearer Token is generated today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found my problem. For token generation I used grant-type "password". With client_credentials it works now.